# How to get the list of markers for a py.test session?

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, fixtures

I am running `py.test` 4.3.1 with `python` 3.7.6 on a Mac (Mojave) and I want to get the list of markers for the 'session', once at the begin of the run.

In `conftest.py` I have tried using the following function:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def collab_setup(request):
    print([marker.name for marker in request.function.pytestmark])
```

which, however, results in an error

```
E       AttributeError: function not available in session-scoped context
```

when I call a dummy test like

```
 py.test -s -m "mark1 and mark2" tests/tests_dummy.py
```

It is important to have the list of markers only once for my testing session, as in the end I want to setup something for all the tests in the testsuite. That is why I must not call this function more than once per test session.

Is this possible to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

The `request` fixture is a 'function' scope fixture that contains information only on the level of the current test to be executed. This is not what we want.

We want the fixture [pytestconfig](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#pytestconfig). This is a 'session' scope fixture that contains the arguments used in the call of `py.test`. And here you can use a method named `getoption` to obtain the markers:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def collab_setup(pytestconfig):
    print(pytestconfig.getoption("-m"))
```

Comment: You can get the value of the `-m` expression easier through `request.session.config.option.markexpr` .  Works from function scope too.

Answer (score 0):

If `collab_setup` is part of class scope, i.e.

```
class TestExampleTest:

    @pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
    def collab_setup(self, request):
        pass
```

You can use `pytestmark` in `self` to get the markers

```
def collab_setup(self, request):
    marks = [mark.name for mark in self.pytestmark]
```